# Getting a char using its decimal index from ASCII

Tags: c, int, ascii

How can I convert (I am not sure if this is the correct term for this case) an int to a char that has this int as a decimal index in the ASCII table? For example, 7 is BEL, 255 is 'ÿ' etc.

I tried searching for a function or a method to do so, but all I can find is people asking how to convert from int to char literally, e.g. from 0 to '0'.

Comment: The ASCII is a 7 bit code and only defines codes 0..127. And your question is too broad. What have you tried? Post your code and where your **specific** problem is.

Comment: you can just treat the int as a char if it's between 0..127.  no conversion is necessary.

Comment: `char` is an integer type. C does not have a distinct character type like some other programming languages.

Comment: My conversion from strings with hexadecimal numbers to integers before in the code was incorrect. Now it works for integers below 127 like you said. 

I need to be able to select pixels in a BMP image using hex values that are in a string form from the beginning. I converted these strings to decimal ints and now I can select pixels with RGB values 0x7F (which is 127) and below. How cam I use ints from 128 to 255 to be able to compare against the rest of the bytes in the pictrure with RGB values above 0x7F?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No conversion needed. Your question explains what C is doing internally (*Converting an int to a char that has this int as a decimal index in the ASCII table...*)

See the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int index;
    char c;

    printf("Enter the ASCII index: ");
    scanf("%d", &index);

    c = index;
    printf("The ASCII char is %c\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C a char can be defined as follows

```
int   a = 'a';
char  b = 'a';
assert(a == b);
```

Even with warnings turned on it won't give a warning because it's valid.

Note that a is of type `int`. The danger lies in doing it this way

```
//some_integer might be 16/32/64... bits
int  a = some_integer;
char b = some_integer;
assert(a == b);
```

This will likely fail so you need to check it. You can see the danger by trying something like this...

```
int test = 353;
char c   = test;
assert(a == c); 
printf("c=%c\n", c);
```

The assert does not fail in the above code because

```
97 == (353 % 256)
```

and this is the character code for `a` in ASCII.

Note, the danger lies in you not getting what you expect.

```
if(some_integer <= 127 && some_integer >= 0) {
   //It's valid 7 bit ASCII
   char ascii_char_7bit = some_integer;
}
```

If you wanted 8 bit you would use

```
if(some_integer <= 255 && some_integer >= 0) {
   //It's valid 7 bit ASCII
   char ascii_char_7bit = some_integer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program that shows the concepts. It uses a `decimal index` as you requested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main(argc, argv)
{
    unsigned char charTable[256];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<256;i++) {     // populate table
        charTable[i] = i & 255;
    }
    printf("%c\n", charTable[97]);      // lower case 'a'
    printf("%c\n", charTable[34]);      // double quote
    for(i=65;i<65+26;i++) {  // upper case alphabet
        printf("%c",charTable[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=97;i<97+26;i++) {  // lower case alphabet
        printf("%c",charTable[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```